# Flex-Mojos compile fxg

Tags: apache-flex, maven, hudson, flexmojos, flex-mojos

Does anyone have a sample pom.xml or a tip of how to get flex-mojos to compile FXG files?

We use some FXG images in our project by adding them in mxml like:

The image ns refers to a package containing the FXG image files.
In Eclispe this works fine.

But when flex-mojos is compiling the project we get a "Type not found" error.

We get the same error in eclipse when we delete the FXG but keep the tag in MXML.
So it looks like maven/flex-mojos is ignoring the FXG files in the image directory.

Comment: Can you give more content? like more about the error, the code you're trying? I've seen flexmojos compile it before, but you're probably just not targeting the correct Flex SDK, be sure it's pointing at 4.0 or higher.  Either that, or you have a weird project setting which eclipse can see the file, but flexmojos can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working now.

The problem in our case had to do with the fact that our FXG was placed in the Assets folder which was a second source folder of the project.

For some reason Flex-Mojos was not able to compile this.
We moved our FXG files from the assets folder into the main source folder and now in compiles.

This problem only occurs on FXG files, other assests in the assets folder like images are compiled correct.

The SDK we are using is 4.5.0.20967 with FM 4.0-beta-7.